# laravel not showing date portion of timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to insert a value for a date into my datatables instance but I can't quite get the format right.

My controller is pulling in a mysql timestamp called 'created_at':

```
if( $d->created_at > $deadline){
    $d->call_status = 'new';
}
```

I'm dumping this and it returns the correct data, and currently in my datatables it dumps the correct data, however it's a full timestamp.

So this:

```
<td class="createdAt">
    @if(!is_null($this->created_at))
        {{ $this->created_at }}
    @endif
</td>
```

Works but returns 06/12/2018 00:00:00

I just want the date portion. However, when I try this:

```
<td class="createdAt">
    @if(!is_null($this->created_at))
        {{ $this->created_at->date->format('Y-m-d') }}
    @endif
</td>
```

It says it can't call format() on a string.

The format line works on my other columns but those are mysql DATE fields, not timestamps.

What would be best practice to get this to properly show the date portion only?

Comment: It is not 100% clear where created_at is coming from. If you are using it inside your Controller as ```$this->created_at``` you would need to show some more code, ie. where you get the created_at from.

Comment: I can show more, but I'll have to edit out the unnecessary. Basically I'm performing a query in the controller since there is no model. In the query I'm using get(['created_at']) and setting it as above. If I dump it, I get "2018-06-02 00:00:00". So it's timestamp format but it is a string

Comment: The inside the Controller use ```Carbon::parse``` as I showed to help you. Alternatively when you get the ```created_at``` make sure it is a valid Date object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) if it is inside Models.

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];
```

Alternatively depending on where you use it.

```
Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use mutators , try this:
In your model create

```
public function getCreatedDateAttribute(){
return date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->created_at));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime()` Will convert your string to a timestamp format, so maybe try like this :

`{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created_at->date)) }}`

Comment: This gave me a date and got rid of the error but gives the dreaded 1969-12-31 date

Comment: `$this->created_at->date` is __NULL__

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

You shouldn't need it, but you can update your model if this is still a string:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at'];
```

Comment: unfotunately, still says I'm calling format() on string

Comment: hmm, I just added an update to the answer which should fix that, but I don't know why it's a string unless `$timestamps` is set to false on the model.

Comment: Ok thank you. Unfortunately, this code isn't using a model for this query but it gives me an idea on where to go from here